# What are the correct C types to use in Idris FFI?

Tags: c, integer, precision, ffi, idris

When making an FFI to C from Idris, the following Idris types [are allowed](https://idris2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ffi/ffi.html#primitive-ffi-types)

> `Int`
> `Char`
> `Double` (as `double` in C)
> `Bits8`
> `Bits16`
> `Bits32`
> `Bits64`
> `String` (as `char*` in C)
> `Ptr t` and `AnyPtr` (both as `void*` in C)
>
> Return types can be any of the above, plus:
>
> `()`
> `PrimIO t`, where `t` is a valid return type other than a `PrimIO`.

Except where the C types are mentioned (`double`, `char*` and `void*`), I'm unclear what C types I should be using. I'm mostly confused about numeric primitives, which I surmise must all correspond to `Int` in Idris.

For example*, if my C function expects or returns an `unsigned int`

```
unsigned int increment (unsigned int x) {
    return x + 1;
}
```

should I use the `increment` C function as is, with `Int`, or should I first cast that to or from `int` before returning it?

```
int increment (int x) {
    // obviously a silly example, do extrapolate to a meaningful example
    return (int) ((unsigned int) x + 1);
}
```

and if I do, am I open to issues regarding numeric width?

*While I'm mostly interested in integer types, I'd like to know how to FFI with all types.

Comment: What probably happens is that the Idris's FFI library will coerce the `Int` to/from an `unsigned int` as needed, possibly resulting in data loss. This means you'll get the best results from C functions that have integer parameters and return values of the same size and signedness as Idris's.

Comment: Isn't Bits an unsigned integer?

Comment: @michaelmesser I hadn't thought of that. I don't know. If so, it may only be `long` that needs to be considered.